# How to determine page load time with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, network-programming

A production environment could use a more complicated solution. But for dev I did this:

```
localStorage["markTime"] = new Date().getTime();
window.location.href = window.location.href + "dev"

// browser goes off and gets new page but we have a local time where this started

<script> <!-- first line after the head tag (forgetting meta data, etc) -->
    alert(new Date().getTime() - localStorage["markTime"] + "ms");
</script>
```

Does this give an accurate number for the amount of time it took for the page to be downloaded?

Comment: It wouldn't be accurate as the next time your page loads it might have caching then so the time is faster at the time.

Comment: No it does not. Javascript timers are not very accurate, and you should at least save the last time after window.onload or something similar to make sure the page has loaded, but that still won't be very accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional solution for this is to place first part in the beginning of `head`, and second part at the end of `body`. It gives somewhat accurate result, but I guess this is the best you can get.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webpagetest.org/ is an excellent resource for measuring load time

If you're looking for a javascript solution, you could sort of profile the time using the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ()
{
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        var endTime = new Date().getTime();
        alert("Page took " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms to load");
    }, 0);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No chance for a very accurate result with javascript inside the same page but, I think this is the closest to it:

```
var loadTime, loadEnd, loadStart = new Date().getTime();
window.onload = function() {
    loadEnd = new Date().getTime();
    loadTime = loadEnd - loadStart;
    console.log(loadTime + " ms.");
}
```

You should place this code in the head, before all other stuff.